# django-channels nginx settings

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels

My django app uses django-channels. 
I was able to configure django to run using gunicorn and nginx. 
The app run if i use python manage.py runserver and redis-server sends notification etc but i am unable to configure it using nginx.

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/amir/clientcode;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/amir/clientcode/adminpanel.sock;
    }
}
```

However when I try to configure it for django-channels it is giving me status 502

```
upstream channels-backend {
    server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/amir/clientcode;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/amir/clientcode/adminpanel.sock;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://channels-backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

My asgi.py file

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "adminpanel.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
``
```

Comment: Have you started daphne in prodcution environment? I use channels here and don't anything in NGINX, just started daphne.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Explanation is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, install Daphne in your app:
Here  I use daphne==1.3.0

To start Daphne server, I use this command:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="config.settings"
exec daphne -b 0.0.0.0 --proxy-headers config.asgi:channel_layer
```

Besides Daphne, you have to start a worker:

```
python manage.py runworker
```

With this, you can use the sockets in the same URL's Projects.

Take a look in this article: https://medium.com/labcodes/introduction-to-django-channels-d1047e56f218

Regards

Comment: I needed to add daphne command in my gunicorn settings and run it via nginx. Thank you for pointing the right direction. This is not the complete answer but I will mark it as accepted one

Comment: Why are you integrating daphne into a gunicorn environment instead of using daphne as the application server (thus: instead of gunicorn) and nginx just as the reverse proxy?